# How to remove unassigned images from products in magento?

Tags: php, database, image, magento

I am using **magento**. I uploaded product sheet (CSV file) with images path of import folder twice. So each product has some UNASSIGNED images with it.

So how can i remove the all unassigned images to attributes of all products.

Any method to remove images path *from database* or other is appreciated.